# Why I receive 404 error use Spring MVC framework?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

When I send request http://localhost:8080/pets My server response 404!
The code on github: https://github.com/Teemitze/petstore

I build war file. Version spring 2.2.6.RELEASE

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/pets")
public class PetsController {

    @Autowired
    PetRepository petRepository;

    @PostMapping("/addPet")
    public void addPet(Pet pet) {
        petRepository.save(pet);
    }

    @GetMapping
    @ModelAttribute
    public String pets(Model model) {
        List<Pet> petList = new ArrayList<>();
        petList.add(getPet());
        petList.add(getPet());
        petList.add(getPet());
        model.addAttribute("pets", petList);
        return "allPets";
    }

    public Pet getPet() {
        Pet pet = new Pet();
        pet.setId(1L);
        pet.setName("Мурзик");
        pet.setPrice(100);
        pet.setBirthday(Date.valueOf("2019-12-12"));
        pet.setSex("М");
        return pet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked out your code and found a few issues.

1) Package structure

Move controller, dto, repo packages to the main package (com.petstore)

Since the main application is inside the (com.petstore) package and the controller is outside the package, so it fails to scan the class.

2) Use annotation @Entity for the Pet entity class with @Id for the id property

3) Remove @ModelAttribute from pets() method since you are not binding any method parameter.

After this, I see the /pets

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SpringBoot project requires define some configuration conventions that need to be follow in order to start a minimum application.
Some points you have to consider when you want to start a spring boot application. 
For example:

- Your SpringBootApplication(PetstoreApplication) class should be in the directory level above your other packages so that it can scan all classes.

[image]

- If you want to use SpringData JPA you have to manage your model class

  `@Data
  @Entity
  public class Pet {
      @Id
      private long id;
      private String name;
      private String sex;
      private Date birthday;
      private byte[] photo;
      private int price;`
  }

because it is handled by respository

`public interface PetRepository extends CrudRepository<Pet, Long>`

- Need minimum configuration for Thymeleaf https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html
- You are making a GET request for a resource "/pets" so no need @ModelAttribute in get mapping method

`@GetMapping()
 public String allPets(Model model) {`

- Make sure your html files is under resources/templates directory.

Check out the reference docs

[spring mvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc)

[spring data jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)